How to send progress of a long running playwright test to front end
I have a route for test progress defined in the node backend as SSE (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events),
I am initializing the url in the frontend.
Below is the code in server route file
let clients: Array<any> = [];

router.get('/progress', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    });

    const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify('Starting the test')}\n\n`;

    res.write(data);

    const clientId = Date.now();

    const newClient = {
      id: clientId,
      res,
    };
    clients.push(newClient);
    req.on('close', () => {
      console.log(`${clientId} Connection closed`);
      clients = clients.filter((client) => client.id !== clientId);
    });
  });

I have a button in the frontend which on click will run a playwright test in the node backend.
Since it is a long running playwright test(looping through a csv and checking), I want to send the progress to frontend in between.
I tried importing sendEventsToAll function(defined in the server route file) shown below into the test and calling it, but it is not working,
export function sendEventsToAll(data: any) {
  console.log('SSE ' + data);
  clients.forEach((client) => client.res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`));
}


What is the best way to solve this, Is there any other better approach.
Thanks.

What do you mean by "not working" exactly? Can you share the test, client and CSV so we have a [mcve] to work from? Thanks.

@ggorlen I have added a stackblitz with code, playwright tests cant be run in webcontainer,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-server-stackblitz-webcontainer-demo-vbneqf?file=server.js,tests%2Fexample.spec.js

Thanks, but code should be in the question itself, not an external link.

So it looks like you have route /progress setup to send SSE to clients. Instead of directly calling the sendEventsToAll function you can create a separate function to send the progress update:
    let clients: Array<any> = [];

router.get('/progress', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    });

    const data = `data: ${JSON.stringify('Starting the test')}\n\n`;

    res.write(data);

    const clientId = Date.now();

    const newClient = {
      id: clientId,
      res,
    };
    clients.push(newClient);
    req.on('close', () => {
      console.log(`${clientId} Connection closed`);
      clients = clients.filter((client) => client.id !== clientId);
    });

    // Expose a function to send progress updates
    res.sendEventsToAll = (data: any) => {
        console.log('SSE ' + data);
        clients.forEach((client) => client.res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`));
    };
});

// Function to send progress updates
export function sendProgressUpdate(data: any) {
    // Invoke the function added to the response object
    res.sendEventsToAll(data);
}

Now from your playwright test, import the sendProgressUpdate and use it to send updates:
import { sendProgressUpdate } from './yourRouteFile'; // Replace 'yourRouteFile' with the path to your route file

// Inside your Playwright test loop or wherever you want to send updates
// Assuming you have some variable 'progressData' containing the progress information
sendProgressUpdate(progressData);


I have done this but data was not streamed in the context of a Test
